# Panning and zooming to an SVG element

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to pan and zoom svg to an svg's elements(a circle and rectangle in my example) when user click their links as in this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/n9xauq6j/9) but the svg does not move, here is my code(I'm using viewBox="0 0 1200 1200")

```
    var svg = d3.select("#svg");
    var placePositionX = svg.select("#" + id).attr("cx");
    var placePositionY = svg.select("#" + id).attr("cy");
    translate = [ placePositionX, placePositionY ];
    var g = svg.select("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")")
```

I'm using D3 version 3.

The expected behavior is when user click on Circle link the map should zoom and pan to the circle element in the svg (same behavior for rectangle link the svg should pan and zoom to rectangle element in the svg)...the behvior is like google map, when you search for a city the map pan and zoom to that city.

Comment: A minor fix: https://jsfiddle.net/n9xauq6j/9/

Comment: Thanks I updated the question to use this version of JSFiddle

Comment: Can you elaborate about the expected behaviour?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: You can also check this example https://jsfiddle.net/bumbu/167usffr/

Comment: I'm not looking for zooming and panning entire svg, i'm looking for zooming and panning particular points in the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the 
[*solution*](https://jsfiddle.net/mohdasalah/n9xauq6j/10/)  by my self, I should first translate it to window size:

```
    var g = svg.select("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + window.innerWidth/2 + "," + (window.innerHeight)/2 + ")scale(" + scale + ")translate(" + -placePositionX + "," + -placePositionY + ")");
```